# Which distribution is this one?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Each one of n equal balls falls randomly on one of n equal cans.

When the cans are sorted by the number of balls they are holding, which distribution is that one?

I need to find a math library for my code, but don't know the name of the distribution for which I need to find a libary.

Comment: What question is your code meant to answer?  If it weren't for the statement regarding the cans being sorted by the number of balls they are holding, I would have described this as a multinomial distribution.  Very probably, you don't *need* a library to import for this exact scenario though... it is easy enough to derive the formula yourself.

Comment: @JMoravitz I have multiple needs. I could code it, but is bad practice, because maintained libraries are already debugged, and reinventing the wheel is an extreme bad idea in programming.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Are you just trying to get the list of possibilities?  Are you trying to ask what the probability that a particular possibility is achieved?  Are you treating balls as indistinguishable?  Are you treating cans as indistinguishable?  If both are set as indistinguishable and you are merely interested in the list or number of possible results, these are [partitions (combinatorics/number theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).  As for a name for a distribution whose outcomes are partitions, I don't know of such a name and doubt one exist

Comment: Be aware, that the process you describe of distributing balls to cans, then looking only at the number of balls in said cans, and then sorting those numerical results, the outcomes you are describing are *not* equally likely to occur.  Had we treated balls and cans as distinguishable, each distribution of balls into cans will be equally likely.  There are $n!$ outcomes where one ball is put into each can, which would have corresponded to the partition $1,1,1,\dots,1$ and counted only once there.  Meanwhile there are only $n$ outcomes where all balls are put into a single can.

Comment: @JMoravitz I need to calculate, as example, what is the can size required for a million balls, what is the probability of a can not being able to hold all the balls, what percentage of balls are on the 10 most filled cans. For example, if the answer it were "it is a pareto distribution", I would expect that 80% of balls would fall on 20% of cans, and if I had 5 cans, the size should be able to hold close to 80%.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume $b$ balls and $c$ cans. For a particular can, the number of balls is distributed following a Binomial law of count $b$ and probability $\frac 1c$. Hence we have $c$ i.i.d. random variables $B(n;b,\frac1c)$.

Now after sorting, the distribution of the $r^{th}$ number is given by

$$p(n_r=n)=p^r(n_r\le n)p^{c-r}(n_r>n)=(\text{cdf}_B(n;b,\tfrac1c))^r(1-\text{cdf}_B(n;b,\tfrac1c))^{c-r}.$$

This distribution is related to the cumulated Binomial distribution, which has no specific name, AFAIK.